# Add GroundOverlay to StreetViewPanoramaFragment or StreetViewPanoramaView with Google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view, gmsgroundoverlay

Don't close this question as a `duplicate` or `too-broad`.

I have implemented `StreetView` in my demo app and working fine with the use of code :

```
SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment supportStreetViewPanoramaFragment = (SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);
    supportStreetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                StreetViewPanoramaCamera camera = new StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder()
                        .zoom(streetViewPanorama.getPanoramaCamera().zoom)
                        // .tilt(streetViewPanorama.getPanoramaCamera().tilt)
                        .bearing(200)
                        .build();

                streetViewPanorama.animateTo(camera, 500);
                streetViewPanorama.setPosition(melbourne);
            }

        }
    });
```

Now I want to add(use) `GroundOverLay` with `StreetView`. But as far i have been searched a lot and found that we can't add overlay directly to `StreetView`. Also there is no any way to add `StreetView` in `GoogleMap` too.

So is it mandatory to use `Google Map JavaScript V3` or from google map v2 we can add overlay to streetview?

Advanced help would be appreciated !